# Basis of a subspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given
$$ A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
   0 & 0 & -2
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
consider the subspace $W$ of $\Bbb{R}^{3}$ given by $W= \{x \in \Bbb{R}^{3}: Ax = −2x\}$. Find a basis for W

Comment: Have you studied eigen values yet?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The space $W$ is precisely the null space of $A+2I$. You only need to solve the linear system: $$(A+2I)x=0.$$

**Edit.** Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$. Then $Ax=-2x$ yields
\begin{align*}
Ax=\begin{bmatrix}
-x_1-x_2 \\ x_2 + x_3\\ -2x_3
\end{bmatrix}=-2x=\begin{bmatrix}
-2x_1 \\ -2x_2 \\ -2x_3
\end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
Comparing the entries pairwisely,
\begin{align*}
-x_1-x_2=-2x_1 \\ x_2 + x_3=-2x_2\\ -2x_3=-2x_3. 
\end{align*}
I believe you can complete the following steps.

Comment: Yes. For each $x\in W$, we have $Ax=-2x$. That is, $0=Ax+2x=(A+2I)x$.

Comment: Try substituting an arbitrary $x = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix}$ into $Ax = -2x$, and getting three equations in $a, b, c$. You should find that you get infinitely many solutions, which means $W$ will be a non-trivial subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: As pointed out by @user847970, I added more details for that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}$
You need to describe the subespace $W$
consider the product of the matrix by the vector $m=(x,y,z)$ you should get
$$Am=(-x-y,y+3z,-2z)$$
but $-2m=(-2x,-2y,-2z)$
therefore $Am=-2m$ if and only if
$$-2z=-2z \rightarrow z=z$$
$$y+3z=-2y \rightarrow y=-z$$
$$-x-y=-2x \rightarrow x=y=-z$$
With this our objetive is characterize all the vectors of $W$ which are of the form
$$(-z,-z,z)=z(-1,-1,1)$$
therefore a basis for $W$ are
$$\beta= \lbrace (-1,-1,1) \rbrace$$
and
$$Dim_W=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is $\rm{det}(A-xI)=(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$.  The eigenvalues are thus $1,-1$ and $-2$, each with geometric multiplicity one.  Thus the dimension is one.

So we need $A\vec v=-2\vec v$.  Then we can compute the kernel of $A+2I$.  We get $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&3&3\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Thus by back-substituting, we get $(1,1,-1)$ as a basis.